# using css and javascript onclick, link color change when they are clicked and being activated untill I click other link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do this: user clicks link, then the clicked link turns yellow and stay yellow until I click a link that's next to the clicked link. so they need to toggle. (not :active) this should be done with onclick I think. I personally want to do with css tho.

```
<div id="Space">
    <ul>
        <li role="presentation" class="sort">
            <a href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">hot</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="date">
            <a href="/?sort=date&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">update</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

currently in css, I have

```css
#Space li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
}

#Space li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6495ED;
}
```

and nothing for js. Javascript goes in html with `<script></script>` right? Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:active` along with `:hover`:

```css
#Space li:active,
#Space li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6495ED;
}
```

Now, this kinda stays till you click another link. But there are better methods using `<input type="radio" />` that persists.

```css
#Space li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}

#Space li:focus,
#Space li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6495ED;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Space">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort" tabindex="1">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">hot</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date" tabindex="1">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">update</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I used `:focus` in the above example, because the `:hover` is tied to the `<li>` and not in `<a>`.

---

JavaScript version could be as simple as adding and removing an `.active` class.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear but this wasn't what I was asking, the below answer is the solution to the one I was asking

Comment: @winixxee Sure... No problem. `:)`

Comment: do you know how to achieve what I'm looking for? the above answer doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

> Use color in hover: selecor

```css
#Space li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
#Space li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6495ED;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Space">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">hot</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a href="/?sort=date&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">update</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, thanks this was what I was looking for, but when I run this on my code it doesnt work. I'm suppose to put js code in html file within<script> </script> no?

Comment: Yes, if I put it at the end it(front-end) works but it when I click it it doesn't go to the link.......do you know why?hmmm...

Comment: Read the answer properly, `e.preventDefault();` is preventing redirection. If you want to redirect then remove that line. But effect will not be visible as user is being redirected to the target url..

Comment: do you know how to redirect the user, and the color of the link to stay in yellow untill I click the other url?

Comment: because that's my initial goal...still haven't done that..

Comment: Color is set on click and by the same time user will be redirected. Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I want the color to stay on untill user chooses to click other button, like the solution you provided; the color stays on untill I click hot from update. I hope to achieve this feature, and the redirecting to work as well

Comment: You do not need JS for this..Check the update...

Comment: you know when you go to youtube, and there's home/trending/subscription below the navbar?once you click trending from home, then there's red border-bottom right?that's what I'm trying to do